# is it possible have tabs in a Salesforce Modal tab as shown in the sample image?

Tags: modal, lightning-tabset

I am trying to implement a Salesforce Modal with Tabs. Is it possible have tabs in a Salesforce Modal tab as shown in the sample image? I tried exploring different articles to see is there any option to have tabs in Modal. I could not spot any? As an alternative, planning to have buttons and to conditionally display the contents according to the button click. However, just wanted to check if anyone has ever implemented Modal with Tabs.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use the CSS from lightning design system to create a modal and inside that use lightning tab component inside it.

Comment: Okay @manjit5190. Thanks, I will check. Any sample that I can refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ manjit5190 Thanks for your inputs! [image]

Added the below kind snippet in my modal. Different Tab style available in the below link -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example

```html
    <lightning-tabset variant="vertical">
        <lightning-tab label="Item One">
            One Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Two">
            Two Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
            Three Content !
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
```